# Error using Terra in R to combine Geometries using combineGeoms

Tags: r, terra

I am trying to eliminate polygons in a multipolygon that have an area smaller than x. This is my code:

```
v = terra::vect(f)
area <- expanse(v)
th <- area < 25
x <- combineGeoms(v[!th], v[th])
```

Most of the time, the code works as it should, but for some reason combineGeoms gives me different errors I don't understand and don't make sense to me such as

> Error: [] nrow dataframe does not match nrow geometry

or

> Error: [combineGeoms] x and y must be polygons

When looking into my files, there are only polygons in my multipolygons (no points or lines).
Also when comparing length of data.frames and the vector files, they have the same amount of rows.
Anybody understand these errors better?

Comment: Unfortunately you have not provided a worked example or access to your data so that we can recreate the issue. As such, one can only speculate and you are likely going to have your post closed. Please provide some data so that we can troubleshoot. Honestly this sounds like a potential bug so, perhapse you should file an issue on GitHub. I would reccomend moving your analysis to sf to see if the behavior is associated with your data.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not finding any tool that replicates combineGeoms in sf. St-Union seems to merge all polygons in multipolygon A with all polygons in multiplygon B. any idea what is the equivalent tool?